# relation "students" does not exist

Tags: postgresql

I am new to postgres and I was following a tutorial on postgres and when I type TRUNCATE TABLE students it says relation "students" does not exists although it exists but the same command works in the tutorial

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Your table is located in the schema `sample` so you need to use:

```
truncate table sample.students;
```

Comment: Thank You it worked but in the tutorial it worked without adding sample. , Is it due to older version in the tutorial ?

Comment: The either put the table in the `public` schema or changed the [search_path](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-PATH)

Comment: Thank you for the answer the search_path was indeed set to sample and i missed it